# Difference between CSS Attribute Selectors and Pseudo-Elements for Input Tags

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, attributes

`<input type="text" placeholder="nothing" title="google" required>`

**Inside CSS file: **

```css
input[type="text"]{
border: 2px solid red;
}

input::placeholder{

color:green;
}

input[title="google"]{
background-color:black;
color:white;
}
```

Why the writting process is different for **type**,**placeholder** and **title**? Though the writting looks same inside  tag. How to understand which are **attribute** and which are **elements**?

Answer (score 0):

`input::placeholder` selects the placeholder of an `<input>`, whereas `input[attribute="value"]` selects an `<input>` whose attribute has a value of value. These do different things.

Visualized example:

```css
/* Selects an <input> with a 'placeholder' attribute */
input[placeholder] {
  color: #2ab7ca;
}

/* Selects the placeholder itself */
input::placeholder {
  color: #ff6b6b;
}


/* Ignore these */

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2em;
}

input {
  display: block;
  margin: 1em 0;
  height: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<input
  type="text"
  placeholder="This placeholder is red and not editable."
>

<input
  type="text" placeholder=""
  value="...whereas the input content itself is blue and editable."
>
```

Note: This answer was converted from a comment as I can't find any duplicate targets.

Answer (score -1):

In CSS, we have attribute selectors and pseudo-elements that serve different purposes and have distinct syntax. Let's understand their differences and how to identify them:

```
Attribute Selectors:
    Attribute selectors allow us to target elements based on their attribute values.
    To use them, we enclose the attribute and its value in square brackets, like this: [attribute="value"].
    For example, in your code, input[type="text"] targets <input> elements that have their type attribute set to "text".
    Similarly, input[title="google"] targets <input> elements with the title attribute set to "google".
    With attribute selectors, we can apply styles to elements based on specific attribute values.

Pseudo-Elements:
    Pseudo-elements, on the other hand, allow us to target specific parts or states of an element.
    We indicate a pseudo-element by using double colons :: before the element name.
    For instance, input::placeholder targets the placeholder text of <input> elements.
    Pseudo-elements enable us to style pseudo-parts or states, such as the placeholder text, first letter, or first line of an element.
```

To differentiate between attribute selectors and pseudo-elements:

```
Attribute selectors use square brackets [attribute="value"] to target elements based on their attribute values.
Pseudo-elements use double colons :: before the element name to target specific parts or states of elements.
```

In your CSS code, the selectors input[type="text"], input[title="google"], and input::placeholder each target different aspects of the  element:

```
input[type="text"] applies styles to <input> elements that have the type attribute set to "text".
input[title="google"] targets <input> elements with the title attribute set to "google".
input::placeholder targets the placeholder text within <input> elements.
```

By using these selectors, we can apply unique styles to specific elements or parts of elements based on their attributes or states.